# Unable to display calendar in correct format when selected from UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I have a UIDatePicker which displays the date using the Islamic Calendar.  The datePicker is displaying the values in the correct format.  However, when I assign the users selection to the UITextField, it unfortunately displays the equivalent date in Gregorian calendar format.  How can I change this so that it displays the Islamic calendar equivalent?

Here is the relevant code:

```
//The below code is what displays the dates from the Islamic calendar in the UIDatePicker (and works correctly):
let islamicCalendar = NSCalendar.init(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic)
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.calendar = islamicCalendar
components.year = 10
let currentDate = NSDate()
let maxDate: NSDate = islamicCalendar!.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: [])!
self.datePicker?.calendar = islamicCalendar
self.datePicker?.minimumDate = NSDate()
self.datePicker?.maximumDate = maxDate
```

This is the block of code which converts the users selection and assigns it to the appropriate UITextField:

```
var selectedDate: String = String()
selectedDate = self.dateformatterDateTime(self.datePicker!.date) as String
myTextField.text = selectedDate

func dateformatterDateTime(date: NSDate) -> NSString {
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

 }
```

Comment: can you check how have you initiated dateformatterDateTime, can you please post that statement here.

Comment: My apologies, the code has been updated.

Comment: No I mean where have you declared it? You might have declared it somewhere like `var dateFormatterDateTime = DateTimeformatter` something like this.

Comment: Thanks make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You should either convert the selected date into islamic date in your `func dateformatterDateTime(date: NSDate) -> NSString` method or send this method a converted date. You can do it so by -

```
var selectedDate: String = String()

var date  = (islamicCalendar?.date(byAdding:components, to:    self.datePicker!.date, options: []))!

selectedDate = self.dateformatterDateTime(date) as String
myTextField.text = selectedDate

func dateformatterDateTime(date: NSDate) -> NSString {
   let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
   return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

or -

```
func dateformatterDateTime(date: Date) -> NSString {
   let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

   var dateToSendBack = (islamicCalendar?.date(byAdding:components, to:  date, options: []))!
   return dateFormatter.string(from: dateToSendBack)
}
```

Comment: I am still getting back the Gregorian calendar version.

Comment: Ok can you share the code over github or something similar so that I can have a look and revert.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
let picker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 0, height: 0))

picker.datePickerMode = .date
picker.date = Date()
picker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleRightMargin
picker.frame.size.width = 300
view.addSubview(picker)
```